# Merge code without creating a new commit id in git

Tags: git, git-merge, git-commit

Is there a good way for doing a merge from some_other_repo_branch into another_branch without creating a new commit_id?

I've been using this:

`git checkout my_branch
git pull --rebase <remote> other_branch_where_are_the_changes`

Comment: Well... to be pedantic, `pull --rebase` *will* create a new commit ID.  It will create new commits that look a lot like your old commits, but they will have new IDs.  Are you worried about *creating merge commits*, or are you worried about *the commit IDs*?

Comment: @EdwardThomson hi. I'm worry about the commit IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing a fast-forward merge (which is the default, if that is possible), git *won't* create a commit. You can explicitely enforce that behaviour by using `--ff-only`:

```
#in another_branch
git pull --ff-only remote some_other_repo_branch
```

Of course, this can only work iff there are no conflicts -- otherwise, git cannot fast-forward, and you'll need to have a commit (because [in theory] you can't go back in time).

reference: `git help merge`, section on "FAST-FORWARD MERGE".

Comment: Note that doing a fast-forward merge doesn't create a commit by default, but you can tell `git` to create one anyway, even though it's a fast-forward (`--no-ff`). Some projects like to require this as an audit trail of exactly when merges were done...

Comment: Perfect, I will dig into this and post my results. And, yes. I would work bc I don't wanna a new commit ID.